# struts2 UI components problem

Tags: html, css, struts2

Why is it that the s:textfield is placed on bottom when I insert it in between other HTML elements inside a form?
How can I fix this?

```
<label><span class="required">*</span>First name</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value=""><br>

                <div>
                <s:select id="selectDrop" list="list" name="list"/>
                </div>

                <label><span class="required">*</span>Last name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br>
```

Result on browser:
First Name
Last Name
"The drop down element"

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML content? You are using struts specific notation (I guess) to generate the select. That is probably somehow the problem. Is creating the other elements with struts as well an option?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually was able to solve by adding the them="simple" in the s:form element.

```
<s:form id="registrationForm" action="/registration/.action" method="post" theme="simple">
```

I guess if I don't add them property Struts2 UI components add their own stylesheet and therefore get weir behavior.

Comment: You can read about the themes here: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/themes-and-templates.html